# How can I query docs base on its field value in other index in ElasticSearch 7

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two indexes in elasticsearch 7.

**How do I sort user docs by age base on user_id in group "abc"**

Here's some sample docs in the indexes.

```
================ index: group ====================
# doc

{
  "abc": [1, 3, 5, 7],
  "efg": [1, 3, 46, 53]
}


================ index: user ====================
# doc

{
  "user_id": 1,
  "age": 28
}


{
  "user_id": 3,
  "age": 21
}


{
  "user_id": 46,
  "age": 29
}
```

Expected Return

```
[
  {
    "user_id": 3,
    "age": 21
  },
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "age": 28
  }
]
```

Or for this propose. I should have my doc structure of **index: group** be below instead of above.

```
  {
    "group_id": "abc",
    "users": [1, 3, 5, 7]
  }
```

Comment: Hi Han, I would advise against it. Elastic is not a relational database. I am not sure how to make it work just yet but ... not a good plan IMHO.
One thing you could do is, to give to store in the user index the groups they belongs to. and then filter on it directly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can't agree more that ES is not a RDB. I did store in the user index the groups they belongs to. example: `{"user_id": 3,"age": 21, groups: [1,3,89,95]}`. But it's really expensive to upsert array: groups. Cause there are like ten thousand plus users have to be upserted when a new group being created. I'm  just looking for if there is better solution.

Comment: Haaaa, sure thing. Then maybe take a look at this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-enriching-data.html it sounds like it could be perfect for you ^^

Comment: Thanks for your information. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: If this sounds like something you want to do, ping me I have been working on it too. I may be able to help